# zepplin mysql interpreter error, Cannot fetch dependencies for mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38

Tags: mysql, maven, dependencies, interpreter

when create new mysql interpreter into appache zepplin, error reported as question title.

environment:

linux centos 7.3
zepplin 0.8.2, bin package installed.
maven 3.1 installed.

create new mysql interpreter, according to official site step:
https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.2/interpreter/jdbc.html#mysql

[image]

Properties -----------------------------------------------

```
Name                Value
default.driver      com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
default.url         jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
default.user        mysql_user
default.password    mysql_password
```

Dependencies ---------------------------------------------

```
Artifact                                   Excludes
mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38
```

when create new note and bind to mysql interpreter, it reports following:

Error setting properties for interpreter 'jdbc.mysql': Cannot fetch dependencies for mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38

[image]

checking also the @zepplin_root_path/local-repo/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38, nothing found.

obviously the dependency is not downloaded.
my question is how to download this artifact.
Is the maven required for zepplin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is because downloading from Maven central repository does not work.

Default Maven Central repository of zeppelin is set to "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
and the above links is not working now.

According to the next article, maven repo has recently stopped supporting http requests.
https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334-Central-501-HTTPS-Required

So, you need to add the following URL as a new repository in Zeppelin.
http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/

In my case it works fine. ( zepplin 0.8.2 )

The HTTPS' URL does not work in zeppelin.
Maybe for some reason Zeppelin doesn't support HTTPS.

Here is a similar article related to this topic :
[Apache Zeppelin not working with https for maven repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60052650/apache-zeppelin-not-working-with-https-for-maven-repo)

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same issue and it has just started recently. This has always worked for me in the past