# Apache Zeppelin not working with https for maven repo

Tags: maven, apache-zeppelin

I'm running Apache Zeppelin 0.8.0 in Amazon EMR. Recently the spark interpreter started to fail to pull down library dependencies. This was because the zeppelin.interpreter.dep.mvnRepo configuration parameter was set to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ and the maven repo has recently stopped supporting http as outlined here: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334

As per the maven documentation I updated the value of this parameter to https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ but this didn't resolve the issue. Instead updating the value to http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/ fixed the problem.

It seems like Zeppelin is not working with https for the maven repo. Can anyone confirm if this is the case or is some extra set up required to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

I was having issues pulling down library dependencies on Zeppelin 0.8.2 with zeppelin.interpreter.dep.mvnRepo set to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ like you mentioned, but for me it works with zeppelin.interpreter.dep.mvnRepo set to https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ only if I set the spark.jars.packages property  in the Zeppelin interpreter GUI to the groupId:artificaftId:version for the library I was trying to pull.