# Not able to download maven dependencies in Apache Zeppelin notebook

Tags: maven, apache-zeppelin

Receiving the following error on trying to download a maven dependency in Apache Zeppelin notebook-

Error setting properties for interpreter 'spark.spark': Cannot fetch dependencies for org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.8

Thanks.

Comment: Updating question with complete error log would help answering the question.

Comment: what version of Zeppelin?

Comment: it should be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60052650/apache-zeppelin-not-working-with-https-for-maven-repo - and in 0.9.0-preview1 it works just fine